# selecting value from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am wondering how to select a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn value as a default? In DataGrid there are 4 columns along with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. A data tabale is binding the grid but for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn I have set values as items collection in design mode.

Can you please help how I can select first item from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn as default ? Currently it shows all items on clicking drop down but as a default or first item it shows empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `NullValue` works, but it has some problems, for example, after selecting other value, i couldn't erase it...
so i used:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // your combo column index 
     {

        e.Value = "Dr.";

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are properties for `DataGridViewColumn` that selects default value when null is selected.

If your `ComboBox` column is data-boumd use:

```
col.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = 1; //this is not index! It is value binded to 'ValueMember'
```

else use:

```
col.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "First";
```

Hope that helps you.